# Detecting when a string exists but doesn't start with - in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to make a bash program that saves results to a file with the name of the user's choosing if the program is supplied the --file argument followed by an option, in which the option should not start with a dash. So I used the following conditional:

```
    if [[ -n $2 && !($2="[^-]") ]]
```

But that didn't work. It still saves the output to a file even if the second argument starts with a dash. I also tried using this:

```
   1) if ! [[ -z $2 && ($2="[^-]") ]]
```

It also did as the previous one. What's the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `=` in `[[ ]]` *isn't* a regular expression, it's a glob-style pattern match.

Comment: @Charles Duffy And what does this mean?

Comment: ...it means the question's terminology is wrong? A "regular expression" is a term for which there's actually a formal definition in the POSIX standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a pattern match, this might look like:

```
[[ $2 ]] && [[ $2 != -* ]]
```

Note:

- Moving `&&` outside of `[[ ]]` isn't mandatory, but it is good form: It ensures that your code can be rewritten to work with the POSIX `test` command without either using obsolescent functionality (`-a` and `-o`) or needing to restructure.
- Whitespace *is* mandatory. In `!($2="[^-]")`, neither the `!` nor the `(` and `)` nor the `=` are parsed as separate operators.
- `=` and `!=` check for *pattern matches*, not *regular expressions*. The regular expression operator in `[[ ]]` is `=~`. Among the differences, anchors (`^` to match at the beginning of a string, or `$` to match at the end) are implicit in a pattern whereas they need to be explicit in a regex, and `*` has a very different meaning (`*` in a pattern means the same thing as `.*` in a regex).
- The `^` in `[^-]` **already negates** the `-`, so by using `!` in addition, you're making your code only match when there **is** a dash in the second argument.

---

To test this yourself:

```
$ check_args() { [[ $2 ]] && [[ $2 != -* ]]; echo $?; }
$ check_args one --two
1
$ check_args one two
0
$ check_args one
1
```

Comment: See the edits, showing how I tested my answer. It certainly behaves the way your original expression reads (using `^-` to negate the match, then using `!` to negate the result).

Comment: ...if you only want *one* of those negations, not both, then you'll want to take out either the `^` or the `!`.

Comment: Oh. I got it. Thanks a lot for your reply. This was a great one. Also, does the `~=` function like the `!` ? or is there a difference?

Comment: Sure -- that's because I treated your pattern as canonical, not your text; they conflict with each other in the question, so a single answer can't be correct both ways. If you want the other one, I'll change it.

Comment: ...made the change, and expanded the explanatory text to explain why that change was necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, Charles. Great details and explanation!